# how to get whole string in different variables?

Tags: android, string

**how to get whole string in different variables?**

> I have single string which contain 5 names and there is a space between every single name,now i want to get these five names in to different ,different string

**for ex i have string like below**

> String name= ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO;

**and i wan to get these string like below(removing space)**

> String a=ABC;
>
> String b=DEF;
>
> String c=GHI;
>
> String d=JKL;
>
> String e=MNO

Comment: You do not refer to which language you're using.

Comment: @Annihlator yeah done

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT: Since you've added that you're using Android, here's the Java version.. I've also left the old python version below for reference]

```
String name = "ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO";

String[] splits = name.split(" ");
String a = splits[0];
String b = splits[1];
String c = splits[2];
String d = splits[3];
String e = splits[4];

System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(d);
```

The pre-edit Python 2.7 version:

```
name = "ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO"

a, b, c, d, e = name.split()

print(b)
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replace(" ","");
```

or

```
String name = yourString.replace(" ","");
```

or

```
str.split();
```

Answer (score 0):

For PHP/Java/JavaScript AND C# the explode() function may be what you're looking for.

Example in PHP:

```
$strings[] = explode(" ", $name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the majority of languages/libs have some kind of string.split(); function.